# Why is Laravel throwing an error like "Call to a member function make() on null in..."?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have defined constant.php file inside app folder like `app/constant.php`.
And I have defined my upload url like:

```
define('DIR_UPLOADS', url('/').'/uploads/');`
```

but it throws the following error:

> Call to a member function make() on null in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\rabble\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php**
>   on line 53

I have also created a new folder named uploads and I'm using `Laravel 5.1`. I have also tried `composer update` and `composer dump-auto`.

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: improved grammar and added specific question

Answer (score 0):

When config files are loaded the container is not yet fully initialized. When you call **url()** helper, it's trying to get **UrlGenerator** service from the container, but the container instance does not exist yet.

You should also use **Config** facade to store/retrieve global settings instead of defining PHP constants.

What do you want to use this constant for? Please elaborate and I'll find a better place to put it.

Comment: Actully I want to use constant text in laravel app